# Why can't I log into SQL Server using Windows Integrated Security?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write a small app that will log into SQL Server to perform some admin functions. When I connect to SQL Server using the following connection string, I can log in fine:

```
Data Source=Localhost\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=PeteDb;User Id=sa;Password=test;
```

However when I want to use integrated:

```
Data Source=Localhost\SqlExpress;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

How can this be solved? I am in the list of logins.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to specify the Initial catalog in the 2nd connection string?  Something like this:

```
Data Source=Localhost\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=PeteDb;Integrated Security=True;
```

Comment: I want to log into the master db, plus it works on another machine :-(

Comment: Does the sa/test login work when you specify InitialCatalog=master?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue setting up and instance of SQL Server.  [This tutorial](http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/) worked for me.